# How to avoid fractions when writing expressions?

Tags: notation

When I'm writing expressions in an articles the fractions when not segregated in a single equation usually are a problem. One example is $\frac{x}{\log y}$ that can be written as $x\log y^{-1}$.

Another situation is when you have a long expression and want as the result half of this result. Example: $\frac{a + b + c + d + e + f}{2}$. It could also be written as $(a + b + c + d + e + f) \cdot 1/2$ or $(a + b + c + d + e + f) \cdot 0.5$ (with the symbol because without could not be clear enough).

1) Is there any better and more compact way to express that (half of a given expression)?

2) Are there any other situations where you use this kind of simplification (as in the example one) to avoid writing fractions?

Comment: I'd just write them as $x/(\log y)$ and $(a+b+c+d+e+f)/2$ if vertical format couldn't be used.

Comment: I agree with $(a+b+c+d+e+f)/2$; or I might write $(1/2)(a+b+c+d+e+f)$.

Comment: $\frac{x}{\log y}$ cannot be written as $x\log y^{-1}$; the two expressions have completely different meanings..

Comment: MJD, could you please give more details about that?

$10 log(100)^{-1} = \frac{10}{log(100)} = 5$ no?

Comment: You can use $2^{-1}$ to express $\frac{1}{2}$ so $\frac{a+b+c+d+e+f}{2}=2^{-1}*(a+b+c+d+e+f)$

Comment: The problem is that $\log y^{-1}$ is more likely to be interpreted as $\log(y^{-1})$ than as $(\log y)^{-1}$ (and these are very different things).

Comment: So $x(logy)^{-1}$ would be right?